# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql//127.0.0.1:3306/java Error - JDK 1.8, mysql-connector 8.0.12

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I tried searching for a solution but the questions on this website just weren't the answer I'm looking for.

I tried running:

```
private static final String USERNAME= "root";
private static final String PASSWORD= "root";
private static final String CONN_STRING= "jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/java";

conn Connection = null;

try{
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(CONN_STRING, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
    System.out.println("Connected");
} catch (SQLException e){
    System.err.println(e);
}
```

I've got the 8.0.12 version of both server and connector.

Comment: Maybe you are missing a `:` in the jdbc string - try `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/java`

Comment: OMG you're right! Thanks a lot man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JDBC URL should follow `jdbc:mysql://localhost/test` format as per 
[7.1 Connecting to MySQL Using the JDBC DriverManager Interface](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html) docs.

You are missing a semicolon after `mysql` part, it should be

```
private static final String CONN_STRING = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/java";
```